# Como trabalhar com Parallel usando a biblioteca NInject

Tags: c#, paralelismo, ninject

Como é possível configurar o ninject para que ele disponibilize uma instância de um determinado objeto por cada thread que o chamar?

O kernel do ninject pode ser executado antes de um código com paralelismo ou é necessário instanciar um novo kernel dentro do código da thread?

Ao executar o código abaixo, obtenho erro de datareader existente aberto.

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new FooModule(), BarModule());

Parallel.ForEach(entidades, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, (entidade) =>
{
    //Algum código aqui
    kernel.Get<IService>().Consultar(entidade);
}
```

Ao colocar a criação do kernel na thread, não obtenho o erro de datareader aberto mas identifico que o Ninject não está dando o dispose nas conexões com o banco quando a thread é finalizada.

```
Parallel.ForEach(entidades, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, (entidade) =>
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel(new FooModule(), BarModule());
    kernel.Get<IService>().Consultar(entidade);
}
```

> Additional information: Tempo limite expirado. O período de tempo
>   limite foi atingido antes que fosse obtida uma conexão do pool. Isso
>   pode ter ocorrido porque todas as conexões do pool estavam em uso e o
>   tamanho máximo do pool foi atingido.

Answer (score 0):

O Ninject só irá tentar fazer o dispose do seu objeto se você definir o scope dele. No seu caso acredito que o scope adequado é o InThreadScope.

```
Bind<IService>().To<MyService>().InThreadScope();
```

Comment: Vinícius, tentei definir este escopo para o serviço mas a exceção continuou a ser levantada como se a mesma instância estivesse sendo utilizada para diferentes threads.